# Selecting a node value based on the value of a parent's child node with Xpath Predicates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, biztalk

I have this structure, where I need to select a value from a node, if the child of its parent 4 steps up contains a specific value.

So far I've tried the follow xPath:

```
<Contact>
    <Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="EFACT_D01B_ORDERS/NADLoop1/CTALoop1/CTA/C056[../../../NAD01 = 'PO']/C05601"/>
    </Id>
</Contact>
```

The value I need is in C05601.

This is the structure of the schema, with the two important nodes marked in blue:

[image]

The structure is also looped, and occurs multiple times in the input document. Basically, if NAD01 = "PO", then the value from C05301 should be mapped to the Contact/Id field.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the condition up to the common ancestor instead...

```
<xsl:value-of select="EFACT_D01B_ORDERS/NADLoop1[NAD/NAD01 = 'PO']/CTALoop1/CTA/C056/C05601"/>
```

(Note, I think your current statement doesn't work because you missed out the `NAD` from the expression)